# Selenium + Firefox + Geckodriver not loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Currently I'm writing some unit tests for a Django project.

However when Selenium loads up the page, it doesn't load jQuery and I get this in geckodriver.log:

```
JavaScript error: http://localhost:59726/, line 370: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

The script is in the `head` tag:

```
<script src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

The page loads fine in Firefox. Any ideas?

selenium version 3.14 
geckodriver 0.21 
firefox 61.0.1

Comment: try removing slash from the begining of src value

Comment: that doesn't work. but i found it will load jquery from the CDN, but not from /static.  It will not load any scripts from /static.  Incredibly confusing.  Again it works in a normal firefox browser, but selenium refuses to load <scripts> from a local resource

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is multifold:

- Django unit tests will not run Nginx but rather its own internal web server.  This web server runs with Debug = False, and will not serve static files.  Thus you will need to use `StaticLiveServerTestCase` instead of `LiveServerTestCase`
- Django 2.0 has a bug where `StaticLiveServerTestCase` doesn't work.  ("Nonetype not callable").  Upgrade to Django 2.1
- Static files must be in a place where the staticfiles app finder can find them.  Just having files in `STATIC_ROOT` isn't enough.  They must be in an app folder, example `/project/app/static/`.  So yes you may have to duplicate all your static files.

After this Selenium should be able to load the local resources.